# Why do I see "server did not agree on a protocol" and no outbound "CERT verify" when trying to configure mTls

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, mtls

I am trying to follow [this](https://medium.com/ing-tech-romania/a-simple-mtls-guide-for-spring-boot-microservices-c6bfc9878369) guide but when I try to run `curl -v -k --cert-type P12 --tlsv1.2 --cert ./src/main/resources/ssl/client_keystore.p12:changeit https://localhost:8443/test` I get

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8443...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=Unknown; ST=Unknown; L=Unknown; O=Unknown; OU=Unknown; CN=localhost
*  start date: Jan 12 01:41:59 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Jan  9 01:41:59 2034 GMT
*  issuer: C=Unknown; ST=Unknown; L=Unknown; O=Unknown; OU=Unknown; CN=localhost
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
* using HTTP/1.x
```

The linked article says I should see 2 `CERT verify` if everything is working, an in and an out. But as you can see I only get an in.

My application.yml on the server looks like this...

```yaml
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:ssl/keystore.p12
    key-store-password: changeit
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: mykey
    key-password: changeit
    trust-store: classpath:ssl/truststore.p12
    trust-store-password: changeit
    trust-store-type: PKCS12
    client-auth: need
    enabled-protocols:
      - TLSv1.2
      - TLSv1.3
  port: 8443
```

If I change to

```yaml
    enabled-protocols:
      - TLSv1.2
```

So no 1.3 I get

```
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
```

Comment: If you try TLS 1.3 do you get the same issue?

Comment: If I change to 1.3 I get `curl: (4) A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.`. This is on a mac

Comment: It *seems* that your server wants TLS 1.3 but you've got a curl that can only handle TLS 1.2.  If you use an up to date browser is it the same thing?

Comment: I tried adding 1.2 in enabled-protocols but that didn't help I get the same

Comment: Full project available here 

https://github.com/jrgleason/spring-boot-mtls But remember I am using curl not the client for now.

Comment: `curl -v -k https://localhost:8443/test` returns `sslv3 alert bad certificate` so it must be working but because curl isn't built for it I don't see the output message like in the example

Comment: `ALPN: server did not agree a protocol` means the server did not agree to the TLS extension for Application Level Protocol Negotiation i.e. it did not (explicitly) agree to HTTP/2 or HTTP/1.1; curl still uses _HTTP_ negotiation to offer HTTP/1.1 and get either an HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/1.0 response, hence the `using HTTP/1.x`. You don't say what webserver you are using. Also @stdunbar+ `curl --tlsv1.2` means 1.2 OR HIGHER; it does not prevent 1.3 if your OpenSSL supports it which it obviously does because only 1.3 uses msgtype 8. (In contrast `openssl s_client|s_server --tls1_2` means 1.2 ONLY.) ...

Comment: It is correct that if your curl-using-OpenSSL did client auth `-v` would include OUT Certificate 11 AND OUT CERT Verify 15 -- in either 1.3 or 1.2 (or below, which you shouldn't use) although for 1.2 they would often be separated by Client key exchange 16. Look at your P12 to make sure it actually contains a cert and privatekey as expected; depending on how curl implements this the client cert may need to be issued from a CA in the server's truststore.

Answer (score 0):

I need to go back and write up the solution but this should work...

https://github.com/jrgleason/spring-boot-mtls/